# Pass a Vue2 bind variable to javascript function in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a menu list in Vue.  I want to call a javascript function when the user clicks on an item.  I have the v-for working fine and the menu displays as intended. But how do I pass a value to the javascript function that I want called?  I have this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:loadNavigation('{{menuItem.name}}')" v-for="menuItem in menuBlock.menuItems">{{menuItem.shortName}}</a>
```

How do I pass the menuItem.name to my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
<a v-bind:href="'javascript:function('+message+')'">{{ message }}</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/okuba3wt/

Answer (score 2):

Make your navigation function a vue method and call it with [v-on:click](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) like so:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" v-on:click="loadNavigation(menuItem.name)" v-for="menuItem in menuBlock.menuItems">{{menuItem.shortName}}</a>
```

In the vue `scripts`:

```
…
data: {
  …
},
methods: {
  loadNavigation: function (event) {
    // Do your thing
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by make it a "vue method?"

Comment: See my updated example and check the doc in the link above.